# How to pass the javascript object from view to controller using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried to pass the customer class object to Asp.net MVC controller using angularJS $http service.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope,$http)
{   
    $scope.getRecord = function () {

        $scope.objCustomer = { Id: 5, Name: 'sasi', Dept: 'IT' };               
        $http({ url: "Home/GetCustbyID", 
                method: "GET", 
                params: {objCustomer: $scope.objCustomer} })
        .then(function (response) 
            {    
             //success code
            };});
}});
```

Controller Action is defined like:

```
public JsonResult GetCustbyID(Customer objCustomer)
{
   return Json(objCustomer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However in the above controller action customer object is always passed as null. Did i miss anything?

Please help me guys to resolve this.

Comment: If you want to send multiple params in a JSON object, you should use POST instead of GET

Comment: Post your Controller "Home/GetCustbyID" code. If it is a get by Id, why do you need Name and Dept?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Arkantos. Yeah !! Its working fine after I changed it to POST method. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `POST` request if you wish to send multiple parameters at once in a JSON object in your AJAX request and capture that as an Object on your server side.

```
$http.post(url, $scope.objCustomer)
     .then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are actually sending data to server you are posting  in `$http`.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope,$http)
{   
    $scope.getRecord = function () {

        $scope.objCustomer = { Id: 5, Name: 'sasi', Dept: 'IT' };               
        $http({ 
                url: "Home/GetCustbyID", 
                method: "POST", 
                data:  $.param({ objCustomer : $scope.objCustomer })                
              })
        .then(function(response) {    
             //success code
            };});
}});
```

in other case if you like to send/pass data as json string you will have to use `stringify` like this

```
 var data = $.param({
            json: JSON.stringify({
                name: $scope.name
            })
        });
 $http.post("/path_of_controller", data).success(function(data, status) {
           //do whatever you like
 })
```

Comment: Yes..! What you posted above is correct. This below code is works for me after i changed it to POST method.

$http({ url: "Home/GetCustbyID", 
method: "POST", 
data: { objCustomer: $scope.objCustomer} }).
then(function (response){});});

But I used 'data' instead of params keyword.